# Handle parameter missing exception in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, parameters, strong-parameters

I have a category and product model, where the product model belongs to a category. Currently I have a link on the category show view which takes the user to a new product form and sets the category ID as the category the user clinked the link from.

To make it clearer:
User chooses a category > User clicks new product link on category show view > product form opens with category ID set as previous category.

The problem I have is that if the user goes to /products/new it throws a parameter missing exception as the category ID cannot be found (seeing as a category is not being sent with the address request).

Is there a way I can handle this to prevent the user from simply typing the /products/new address and trying to access the form? What I want is for the user to be redirected to home if they try to create a new product without clicking the link on a category page.

My code for the product controller (relevant to this question):

```
def new
    @product = @category.products.new
  end

def set_category
      @category = Category.find_by(id: params[:category_id]) || Category.find(product_params[:category_id])
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end

private
    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:category_id, :title, :description, :image_url, :price)
    end
```

Link to new product found on category show page:

```
  %p= link_to t('.add'), new_product_path(category_id: @category)
```

Method the exception points to:

```
def product_params
    params.require(:product).permit(
        :category_id, :title, :description, :image_url, :price)
end
```

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if this was a little unclear.

Comment: What do your routes look like? Maybe you need nested resources so that there is no `/products/new` route at all. Also, you don't need the `find_by`, `find`, and `rescue` for `@category`; if your routes are set up properly and `set_category` is bound to the proper controller methods then just a `Category.find` call and the usual Rails `RecordNotFound` handling should be enough.

Comment: Currently I have:
`resources :categories` 
`resources :products`
on separate lines. I assume you mean to set it up with a do clause and products nested under categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just add a condition to your new action that checks for the existence of the param?

```
unless params[:category_id].present?
  redirect_to somewhere
end
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting the same exception. It's pointing to def product params method (I'll put it in my original post), and giving the message "param is missing or the value is empty: product"

Comment: try doing it in a `before_filter` instead

Comment: Perfect, worked a charm. Thank you very much, will mark as answer.